# JavaScript for loop, regarding index

Tags: javascript, for-loop

How to alter this loop, so that it runs for `i = 12`, `18`, `24`, `30` and `36` only?

```
for (var i = 12; i < 36; i++) {
   console.log(i);
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
for (var i = 12; i <= 36; i += 6) {

   console.log(i);

}
```

Answer (score 3):

The `i++` in the `for` statement is what to do before the next iteration of the loop. So in the case of `i++` we're incrementing the variable `i` by one. So if you want to increment by six then you need to add `6` to the variable which will give you:

```
for (var i = 12; i < 36; i += 6) {
    console.log(i);
}
```

Next up, you want to include 36, so you need to change your condition (the bit of your loop that says `i < 36`) to include 36. This is really easy, you just need to change the "less than" to "less than or equal to" :

```
for (var i = 12; i <= 36; i += 6) {
    console.log(i);
}
```

Comment: @NewUser: Your inner `for` loop has `i <=20` as condition, but you are not increasing `i` in that inner loop. The inner loop will run forever which means the outer loop cannot increase `i` to terminate the inner loop.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of doing i++ in your loop, do i += 6. Like this:

```
for (var i = 12; i < 36; i += 6) {
    console.log(i);
}
```

Comment: That will stop before printing 36.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively (though not necessarily better):

```
for(var i, values = [12, 18, 24, 30, 36]; i = values.shift();) {
    console.log(i);
}
```

This shows that you do not need to have an increasing counter in a `for` loop.

Comment: Interesting. For more complicated examples (without a pattern) could be useful.